# Device emulator-5554 is not online - while executing my appium code on android emulator

Tags: c#, android, appium

> [Error: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. (Original error: unknown error: Device emulator-5554 is not online

Im getting above error when at the middle of the test steps.
Im with Appium, C# on android.

Can any one give me a properer solution for above error?

Comment: Can you check - whether its connected properly using cmd "adb devices" and let me know

Comment: Yeah its every time connected properly and screen never get turns off

Comment: can paste me the response?

Comment: info: Chromedriver: Killing any old chromedrivers, running: FOR /F "usebackq tokens=5" %a in (`netstat -nao ^| findstr /R /C:"9515 "`) do (FOR /F "usebackq" %b in (`TASKLIST /FI "PID eq %a" ^| findstr /I chromedriver.exe`) do (IF NOT %b=="" TASKKILL /F /PID %a))
> info: Chromedriver: No old chromedrivers seemed to exist
> info: Chromedriver: Spawning chromedriver with: E:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-chromedriver\chromedriver\win\chromedriver.exe --url-base=wd/hub --port=9515

Comment: > info: Chromedriver: [STDOUT] Starting ChromeDriver 2.18.343845 (73dd713ba7fbfb73cbb514e62641d8c96a94682a) on port 9515
> Only local connections are allowed.
> info: JSONWP Proxy: Proxying [GET /status] to [GET http://127.0.0.1:9515/wd/hub/status] with no body
> info: JSONWP Proxy: Got response with status 200: "{\"sessionId\":\"\",\"status\":0,\"value\":{\"build\":{\"version\":\"alpha\"},\"os\":{\"arch\":\"x86_64\",\"name\":\"Windows NT\",\"version\":\"6.3\"}}}"

Comment: > info: JSONWP Proxy: Proxying [POST /session] to [POST http://127.0.0.1:9515/wd/hub/session] with body: {"desiredCapabilities":{"chromeOptions":{"androidPackage":"com.dtz.au","androidUseRunningApp":true,"androidDeviceSerial":"emulator-5554"}}}
> info: JSONWP Proxy: Got response with status 200: {"sessionId":"d58963249293fad1b1305310d102ff39","status":13,"value":{"message":"unknown error: Device emulator-5554 is not online\n  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.18.343845 (73dd713ba7fbfb73cbb514e6...

Comment: Thanks for info you have provided. Can you just paste response for "ADB devices" from cmd prompt pls. [Expecting that you will connect device and drivers are in place + USB debugging is ON]

Comment: List of devices attached
emulator-5554   device and usb debugging in ON,Actually this happens in the middle of my test running activity.Not al the time, 2 ,3 times per day. I have 60 Appium automated test are running  on the emulator.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the correct device name - "emulator-5554" is probably not your correct device name.

To fix this:

1. Run: `adb devices`
2. It should show: `emulator-5554   device`  ( device means it is online)
3. To get device name use: `adb -s emulator-5554 shell getprop ro.product.name`
4. This will give you a device name use it in set capability i.e.  `cap.SetCapability("deviceName", "VS Emulator 5.5-inch Marshmallow (6.0.0) XXXHDPI Phone");`

Comment: I also forgot mention that use the UUID in capability as well
Code:  var cap = new DesiredCapabilities();
            cap.SetCapability("deviceName", "donatello");
            cap.SetCapability("platformVersionVersion", "6.0.0");
            cap.SetCapability("uuid", "169.254.190.187:5555");
            cap.SetCapability("fullReset", "True");
            cap.SetCapability(MobileCapabilityType.App, "Browser");
            cap.SetCapability("platformName", "VS Emulator 5.5-inch Marshmallow (6.0.0) XXXHDPI Phone");

Comment: Your comment would be easier to read if it is was properly formatted :-) You can edit your answer and copy it there.

Answer (score 0):

> info: Chromedriver: No old chromedrivers seemed to exist...

Could it be driver related?

When you install the Appium server, a chrome driver is being downloaded as well and that is the one being used by default.
Now it could be that the one Appium is trying to use is to old compared to the one installed on the device (or the other way around).

There are couple of workarounds that might fix your issue.

1. Install the latest Chrome app on the phone ([see apkmirror website](https://www.apkmirror.com/apk/google-inc/chrome/))
2. Install Appium with the latest Chromedriver `npm install appium --chromedriver_version="2.16"`
3. Run Appium with a Chromedriver you've downloaded manually `appium --chromedriver-executable /path/to/my/chromedriver`

http://appium.io/docs/en/writing-running-appium/web/chromedriver/